# Write a line from one file to another only if it starts with the given string in Perl

Tags: perl, split

I want to write a program in Perl that reads a file line by line and write the lines into another file. The input file has data in sets(something like a set of lines where a line starts with START and another line starts with END).  From, START to END, its' a set.  The number of lines in each set may or may not vary.

I want to write each set to a different file(file_1.txt, file_2.txt, etc.)

Example:
Input file:

```
START123
DET1
DET2
END123
START123
DET1
DET2
DET3
END123
```

For this, I want 2 files to be created for each set.

Note: There are 940,000 lines in the input file. Approximately, 100,000 sets.

EDIT:

Exactly. The below is creating unique files but, not writing into the files. What am I missing here?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Open Input file
open my $fh_i, "<", "input.txt" or die $!;

# Flag to check if we are inside the block
my $in_block = 0;
my $counter = 0; #Dynamic Filenaming for each Set
my $filename = "output_1.txt"; #Initial filename

# Read line by line into default variable ($_)
while( <$fh_i> ) {
   $in_block = 0 if /^END/;
   
   # Print to target file if we are inside the block
   open (my $fh_o, ">", $filename) or die $!;
   print $fh_o $_ if $in_block;
            
   close $fh_o if /^START/;
   $in_block = 1 if /^START/;
   $counter = $counter + 1 if /^START/;
   $filename = "output_".$counter.'.txt' if /^START/;
}

close $fh_i;
```

Comment: It is expected that you show the code you tried. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code that fulfills your requirements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Open both files
open my $fh_i, "<", "input.txt" or die $!;
open my $fh_o, ">", "output.txt" or die $!;

# Flag to check if we are inside the block
my $in_block = 0;

# Read line by line into default variable ($_)
while( <$fh_i> ) {
   $in_block = 0 if /^END/;
   
   # Print to target file if we are inside the block
   print $fh_o $_ if $in_block;

   $in_block = 1 if /^START/;
}

close $fh_i;
close $fh_o;
```

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for.  I tried to append a counter to the filename inside the loop to make sure the filenames are distinct.  The files are generating with different names but, not writing into the file.

Answer (score 1):

The `..` operator offers a state like block matching when used with the match operator like this:

```
while (<>) {   
    If (/^START/ .. /^END/) {
        # Inside block
```